# Entity Framework LINQ query left join into new object instead of null

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am basically trying to perform a left outer join in my LINQ query but I want to return an empty instance of the left-joined object instead of null. My solution below results in an error:

> *The entity or complex type 'SubObject2' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.*

```
 public MyObjectsHolder GetObjectHolder()
     {
         using (MyEntities ctx = new MyEntities()) 
         {
             var query = (from a in ctx.tableA
                          join b in ctx.tableB on b.FKID equals a.PKID into b_a
                          from b in b_a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                          select new MyObjectsHolder()
                          {
                              SubObject1 = a,
                              SubObject2 = b ?? new SubObject2()
                          });

             return query.FirstOrDefault();
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2):

The LINQ to Entities provider is throwing that because it has no way of properly translating that instantiation into a SQL query (which is what LINQ to Entities does). Since your method is only returning one object, I would recommend that you do the following to compensate:

```
var query = (from a in ctx.tableA
             join b in ctx.tableB on b.FKID equals a.PKID into b_a
             from b in b_a.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new MyObjectsHolder()
             {
                 SubObject1 = a,
                 SubObject2 = b
             });

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();

if(result != null && result.SubObject2 == null) result.SubObject2 = new SubObject2();

return result;
```